# Chrome doesn't use source maps for `console.log(new Error().stack)`

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, source-maps

But it uses source maps for `console.trace()`.

Chrome Version 54.0.2838.0 canary (64-bit)

[image: stack trace]

I expect it to include its source maps in the error stack trace.

Or is there another way to get access to the source maps?

Apparently it was implemented here:  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=357958.